# How to increase width of an element by X pixels? given that the width of element is not fixed . CSS approach required. No JS

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an element . On Hover I want its width to increase by 6px but the width of the element is not fixed. I'm looking for a CSS only approach for this.

Tried using transform/transition in CSS but it didn't work

Comment: How is the initial width defined? Can you post - in the question - your "*[mcve]*" code (this is a polite request, but it's mostly mandatory in order that we can see what you're working with, and suggest useful/practicable fixes).

Comment: What do you mean with *not fixed*? Not defined at all? A percentage? Viewport units? How about `.element:hover { width: calc(not-fixed-value + 6px) }`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change it *directly* on the element, but if you surround the element whose `width` you want to transition with another (wrapper) element, then you can do it.

This worked for me:

HTML:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"> Item </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: auto;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
}

.item:hover {
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
}
```